# Django Rest Framework + Ember.js + rest auth

Tags: django, google-oauth, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

We're building a site using Ember for a frontend app which interacts with our Django Rest Framework API Backend. For Social Authentication we're using [django_rest_auth](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) coupled with [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). The site is mostly all working, except we've run into problems with social authentication. Our local account authentication/registration is working fine.

I've made many projects that use django-allauth, but this is the first time using a restful authentication system. The ember application is able to go and fetch the token from google just fine. The response is something like:

```
{
    authorizationCode: "mYtokEn12345", 
    provider: "google-oauth2", 
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/dashboard"
}
```

I then post the access_token to my endpoint that I've set up according to the [django_rest_auth](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) docs. POST /auth/google {access_token:} but I get an error returned from Google that says "Invalid Credentials". How can I get Invalid Credentials after already Authenticating with Google and receiving my token?

After debugging through the code, I found that I was getting that response from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo during the `complete_login` function in the `allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.views.GoogleOAuth2Adapter` class.

It's trying to run a GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=mYtokEn12345&alt=json but returning Invalid Credentials.

{

```
error: {
    errors: [
    {
        domain: "global",
        reason: "authError",
        message: "Invalid Credentials",
        locationType: "header",
        location: "Authorization"
    }
    ],
        code: 401,
        message: "Invalid Credentials"
    }
```

}

I'm pretty stumped on where to go from here. Anyone have some pointers on why this is happening? Any other code/errors I can give to be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that we weren't using the correct token. We were using the authorizationCode, which is used in another request to receive the token.